# Can someone explain the unsupported operand error I'm getting while running the file blei_lda.py from Building Machine Learning Systems with Python?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, topic-modeling

I have been trying to run the file blei_lda.py from chapter 4 in the book Building Machine Learning Systems with Python with no success. I am using Python 2.7 with Enthought Canopy GUI. Below is the actual file provided from the creators, but there are also multiple copies up on github.

[github repository](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch04/blei_lda.py)

The problem is I'm continually receiving this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\matt\desktop\pythonprojects\pml\ch04\blei_lda.py in <module>()
    for ti in range(model.num_topics):
        words = model.show_topic(ti, 64)
 ------>tf = sum(f for f, w in words)
        with open('topics.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write('\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(w, int(1000. * f / tf)) for f, w in words))
        output.write("\n\n\n")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'
```

I've tried to create a work around, but wasn't able to find anything that worked completely.

I've also searched all over the web and stack overflow for a solution, but it seems like I'm the only person who is having trouble running this file.

```
# This code is supporting material for the book
# Building Machine Learning Systems with Python
# by Willi Richert and Luis Pedro Coelho
# published by PACKT Publishing
#
# It is made available under the MIT License

from __future__ import print_function
from wordcloud import create_cloud
try:
    from gensim import corpora, models, matutils
except:
    print("import gensim failed.")
    print()
    print("Please install it")
    raise

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from os import path

NUM_TOPICS = 100

# Check that data exists
if not path.exists('./data/ap/ap.dat'):
    print('Error: Expected data to be present at data/ap/')
    print('Please cd into ./data & run ./download_ap.sh')

# Load the data
corpus = corpora.BleiCorpus('./data/ap/ap.dat', './data/ap/vocab.txt')

# Build the topic model
model = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(
    corpus, num_topics=NUM_TOPICS, id2word=corpus.id2word, alpha=None)

# Iterate over all the topics in the model
for ti in range(model.num_topics):
    words = model.show_topic(ti, 64)
    tf = sum(f for f, w in words)
    with open('topics.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write('\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(w, int(1000. * f / tf)) for f, w in words))
        output.write("\n\n\n")

# We first identify the most discussed topic, i.e., the one with the
# highest total weight

topics = matutils.corpus2dense(model[corpus], num_terms=model.num_topics)
weight = topics.sum(1)
max_topic = weight.argmax()


# Get the top 64 words for this topic
# Without the argument, show_topic would return only 10 words
words = model.show_topic(max_topic, 64)

# This function will actually check for the presence of pytagcloud and is otherwise a no-op
create_cloud('cloud_blei_lda.png', words)

num_topics_used = [len(model[doc]) for doc in corpus]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(num_topics_used, np.arange(42))
ax.set_ylabel('Nr of documents')
ax.set_xlabel('Nr of topics')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('Figure_04_01.png')


# Now, repeat the same exercise using alpha=1.0
# You can edit the constant below to play around with this parameter
ALPHA = 1.0

model1 = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(
    corpus, num_topics=NUM_TOPICS, id2word=corpus.id2word, alpha=ALPHA)
num_topics_used1 = [len(model1[doc]) for doc in corpus]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist([num_topics_used, num_topics_used1], np.arange(42))
ax.set_ylabel('Nr of documents')
ax.set_xlabel('Nr of topics')

# The coordinates below were fit by trial and error to look good
ax.text(9, 223, r'default alpha')
ax.text(26, 156, 'alpha=1.0')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('Figure_04_02.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line: `words = model.show_topic(ti, 64)`,words is a list of tuples`(unicode,float64)`

eg. `[(u'school', 0.029515796999228502),(u'prom', 0.018586355008452897)]`

So in this line `tf = sum(f for f, w in words)` f represents the unicode, while w represents the float value. And you are trying to sum the unicode values which gives unsupported operand type error.

Modify this line as `tf = sum(f for w, f in words)` , so it will now sum the float values.

Also modify this line `output.write('\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(w, int(1000. * f / tf)) for w, f in words))` for the same reasons.

So the code snippet will look like:

```
for ti in range(model.num_topics):
    words = model.show_topic(ti, 64)
    tf = sum(f for w, f in words)
    with open('topics.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write('\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(w, int(1000. * f / tf)) for w, f in words))
    output.write("\n\n\n")
```